# Center text when using BmFont (MonoGame)

Tags: vb.net, xna, monogame

Is there a way to center text when drawing using BmFont? I'm using the code from here: [Using a BMP image as font in Monogame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453118/using-a-bmp-image-as-font-in-monogame)

The only code change I did was that I added a `_TextWidth` int to `DrawText` which uses `DX - X` to get the text length, then a function `GetTextLength` to return it to the button class, which then takes the `((button width - text width) / 2)` to get the starting point of the text, centering it. However, there seems to be some problems and the text doesn't center using its own text width, but using the next button's text width instead. Returning the text width is fine, but for some reason when it draws on-screen it's always the wrong values.

Added/changed code:

```
Public Sub DrawText(ByVal spritebatch As SpriteBatch, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal Text As String)
    Dim DX As Integer = X
    Dim DY As Integer = Y
    For Each C As Char In Text
        Dim FC As New FontChar
        If _CharacterMap.TryGetValue(C, FC) Then
            Dim sourceRectangle = New Rectangle(FC.X, FC.Y, FC.Width, FC.Height)
            Dim position = New Vector2(DX + FC.XOffset, DY + FC.YOffset)
            spritebatch.Draw(_Texture, position, sourceRectangle, Color.White)
            DX += FC.XAdvance
        End If
    Next
    _TextWidth = DX - X
End Sub

Public Function GetTextLength() As Integer
    Return _TextWidth
End Function
```

Screenshot:

[Uncentered text, which could be centered if the right values were used for each button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aovhb.png)

Comment: i think you are missing origin in draw, `origin` should also be in center of text. `FC.Width/2` and `FC.Height/2`

Comment: @DavorMlinaric The way it draws text here is character by character, rather than the entire thing at once. Is there then a way to draw everything to a buffer first before drawing it once? That way I can use the origin to center it.

Comment: ah yes, true. You can draw whole text by `SpriteBatch.DrawString`

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I can't though, because I'm not using `SpriteFont`. I'm using the custom `BmFont` class (link in OP) that enables the use of custom fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MonoGame.Extended](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended) has an implementation of the BMFont renderer with some improvements from that old tutorial, including a `SpriteBatch.DrawString` extension.

I've also got a tutorial on [my blog](http://dylanwilson.net/bmfont-rendering-with-monogame-extended) about how to set it up. However, it doesn't deal with centering the text so I'll go over that now.

If you choose to use MonoGame.Extended, you should be able to get the centering effect as follows.

First, load your bitmap font as you normally would a `SpriteFont`. Note, that for this to work you'll need to setup MonoGame.Extended with the MonoGame Pipeline tool.

```
_bitmapFont = Content.Load(Of BitmapFont)("my-font")
```

Next, in your `Draw` method you can use `GetStringRectangle` to measure the size of the text, then calculate the the correct position. Something like this (sorry if my VB.net is a little rusty):

```
Dim text = "Start game"
Dim textRectangle = _bitmapFont.GetStringRectangle(text, Vector2.Zero)
Dim textOffset = buttonWidth / 2F - textRectangle.Width / 2F

_spriteBatch.DrawString(_bitmapFont, text, buttonPosition + textOffset, Color.White)
```

Of course, you don't have to use MonoGame.Extended to do this if you don't want too. I think your code just has a bug, because it looks like it's intended to do what MonoGame.Extended does anyway.

As far as I can tell, your code is calculating the width of the text in the `DrawText` method and returning it in the `GetTextLength` method. The problem with this approach is that if you call `GetTextLength` *before* `DrawText` you're going to get the wrong value.

I assume you're doing something like this:

```
Dim y = buttonPos.Y
Dim x = buttonPos.X - buttonWidth / 2F - GetTextLength() / 2F

DrawText(_spriteBatch, x, y, text)
```

Unfortunately, this will **not** work because `GetTextLength` won't return the correct value until *after* `DrawText` runs.

The fix of course, is to actually calculate the text length properly rather than storing it in a member variable during the draw operation.

```
Public Function GetTextLength(ByVal Text As String) As String
    Dim TextWidth As Integer
    For Each C As Char In Text
    Dim FC As New FontChar
    If _CharacterMap.TryGetValue(C, FC) Then
        TextWidth += FC.XAdvance
    End If
    Next
    GetTextLength = TextWidth
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I had to return the value twice through the renderer and BmFont class, then used the same text to calculate the length, but it all worked out just nice.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please accept my answer. Thanks :)